# Track database query performance using schemacrawler

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, performance, schemacrawler

I am trying to find the performance of my database using schema crawler and I am looking out for ways how to do it. I am using a Spring Boot application to do this for my MySQL/PGS database. I used "EXPLAIN" but I am not getting the relevant output.

I got the below using DB tool: `Seq Scan on users u  (cost=0.00..14.30 rows=430 width=160)`

But in Spring Boot, I did not get anything like this. This is the code I used:

```
for (final Schema schema : catalog.getSchemas()) {
    System.out.println(schema);
    for (final Table table : catalog.getTables(schema)) {
        System.out.print("o--> " + table);
        var sql = "EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM " + table;
        try {
            Statement statement = dataSource.get().createStatement();
            var result = statement.execute(sql);
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return;
        }
        if (table instanceof View) {
            System.out.println(" (VIEW)");
        } else {
            System.out.println();
        }

        for (final Column column : table.getColumns()) {
            System.out.printf("     o--> %s (%s)%n", column, column.getType());
        }
    }
}
```

This is just an example, but I am mainly trying to find the performance of a database programmatically using schemacrawler. Kindly help with suggestions. Thanks.